# RESTful APIs for Azure Analytic Services not working

Tags: c#, http, rest, azure

Alright, I'll be straightfoward here. I successfully called Windows Azure Analytic Services's REST APIs for getting and setting the settings for Blob logging and metrics.

However, when I give it a go for tables and queues, I get the following error message:
`AuthenticationFailed` **Server failed to authenticate the request. Make sure the value of Authorization header is formed correctly including the signature. RequestId:9d4436e0-9367-46ed-9967-b3ebe888d2f8 Time:2012-01-16T09:20:09.5141262Z**

The string I use to sign is the following:
`GET\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\nx-ms-date:Mon, 16 Jan 2012 09:04:50 GMT\nx-ms-version:2011-0818\n/<accountname>/\ncomp:properties\nrestype:service`. It works perfectly fine for Blobs.

The most troublesome thing is that I am not getting an `AuthenticationErrorDetail` in my response from Analytic Services. When I tried calling the settings REST APIs for Blobs, I actually got a `AuthenticationErrorDetail` that told me what string the server used to sign. That really helped me construct the above.

Has anyone else gone through something similar?

Comment: If you're using C# to access azure storage, is there a reason you're not using the storage client library?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realised that my REST calls worked for queues too. It did not work for tables, however.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/dd179428.aspx offered more information:

> **2009-09-19 Shared Key Lite and Table Service Format**
>
> This format supports Shared Key and Shared Key Lite for all versions
>   of the Table service, and Shared Key Lite for the 2009-09-19 version
>   of the Blob and Queue services. This format is identical to that used
>   with previous versions of the storage services. Construct the
>   CanonicalizedResource string in this format as follows:
>
> Beginning with an empty string (""), append a forward slash (/),
>   followed by the name of the account that owns the resource being
>   accessed.
>
> Append the resource's encoded URI path. If the request URI addresses a
>   component of the resource, append the appropriate query string. The
>   query string should include the question mark and the comp parameter
>   (for example, ?comp=metadata). No other parameters should be included
>   on the query string.

In the end, it accepted the path `?comp=properties`.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered similar problems - blobs working fine, tables not working - when I incorrectly used DateTime.Now instead of DateTime.UtcNow for x-ms-date header